# Is it possible to modify a C# web application after it's been containerized?

Tags: c#, azure, docker, knative

I have built 2 web applications:

- 1st with C# and Entity Framework
- 2nd as ASP.NET MVC (as a web service)

Now I was asked to **containerize** above with Knative.

**My question is**: after that the above apps are containerized, will it be possible or easy to modify them again? And how?

Please anything can be helpful.

Comment: A container is meant to be replaced, not altered. See various "pets versus cattle" discussions, [like this](https://www.rapid7.com/blog/post/2015/08/07/optimizing-your-container-environment-pets-vs-cattle/)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to update your existing containerized running application in pod rather you can replace it with new pod. You need to create another updated image and follow the rolling update. **Knative is Kubernetes-based platform to deploy and manage modern serverless workloads**. Kubernetes has a feature called 'Rolling Update'.

**Rolling updates**
Users expect applications to be available all the time and developers are expected to deploy new versions of them several times a day. In Kubernetes this is done with rolling updates. Rolling updates allow Deployments' update to take place with zero downtime by incrementally updating Pods instances with new ones. The new Pods will be scheduled on Nodes with available resources.

Kubernetes commands to update (**tutorial with steps**) your application
[Update App](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-interactive/)

Comment: I think you need to re-word your answer - if you create another image and perform a rolling update, that destroys the original pod and replaces it with a new pod created from the new image. It doesn't 'update the existing containerized running application in a pod'.

Comment: Knative doesn't use a rolling update strategy; instead it uses a method called "blue-green" where the user decides the percentage of traffic to each Revision and then Knative scales the number of pods automatically.